# Changing font size and colour in the same line in html

Tags: html

I’m completely new to html and have just learnt how to change the font size or colour in a body of text by doing:

```
<h1 style=“color:red”>example<h1/>
```

Is there any way to add a font size change to this line? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

I tried to add them side by side and then underneath too. E.g:

```
<h1 style=“color:red”;style=“font-size:10px”>example<h1/>
```

And

```
<h1 style=“color:red”
    style=“font-size:10px”
    >example<h1/>
```

These didn’t work. I’m sure its a stupid problem but I’m really new and I’m just trying to grasp how things work.

Comment: Please, for your own benefit, get a book or [follow a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS). This stuff is simply too complicated to make up as you go.

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly invalid. Fix that first. Voted to close for that reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change my font color with html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159839/how-can-i-change-my-font-color-with-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Let me help you.**

**It's quite simple to put two different ones, you just have to use ";"**

ex: `<h1>example</h1>`

For 10px and red color you need to use this ";". Separation

```html
<h1 style="color:red;font-size:10px">example</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codecademy.com/article/html-inline-styles

```
 <h1 style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">example<h1/>
```

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly invalid.